# Fully linear time regular expression matching

Tags: regular-expressions, parsing

Is there an $O(n+m)$ algorithm to check whether a size $n$ regular expression matches a size $m$ string, assuming a fixed size alphabet if that matters?

The standard NFA algorithm is $O(nm)$ worst case.  Groz et al. achieve linear time for a variety of regular expression classes, but not all.  Are there any better results?

Groz, B., Maneth, S., & Staworko, S. (2012, May). Deterministic regular expressions in linear time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Groz et al. explicitly state that the best known algorithm for general regular expressions (as of 2012) is $O(nm(\log\log n)/(\log n)^{3/2}+n+m)$, due to Bille and Thorup 2009, doi:[10.1007/978-3-642-02927-1_16](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-02927-1_16) ([preprint](http://www2.compute.dtu.dk/~phbi/files/publications/2009fremC.pdf)).

For a fixed size alphabet, Sebastian Maneth pointed out to me that $O(n+m)$ is possible for deterministic regular expressions by constructing the Glushkov DFA: each position in the regular expression is one state, and the transitions are determined by the bounded set of symbols that may appear before moving to a position.
However, without fixing the alphabet size, it still holds that "finding a time $O(m+n)$ algorithm remains an open problem" even in the deterministic case.